# ASPNET Eager Loading doesn't work for HashSet

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm working on a project which has Database-First approach.

In the said project, I have `Offer.OfferPlaces` and `OfferPlaces.Offer` relation.

The first one doesn't seem to work, loading it via `Include(x => x.OfferPlaces)` yields empty collection, while loading `Include(x => x.Offer)` works fine and loads related Offer.

Is that a common issue in EFCore, do I have to implement a workaround of sorts or perhaps add something to `OnModelCreating` of the DbContext?

Here's the `Offer` model:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

namespace MarketplaceOffe.DAL.Model
{
    [Table("Offers")]
    public partial class Offer
    {
        public Offer()
        {
            OfferPlaces = new HashSet<OfferPlace>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OfferPlace> OfferPlaces { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the `OfferPlace` model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MarketplaceOffe.DAL.Model
{
    [Table("OfferPlaces")]
    public partial class OfferPlace
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long OfferId { get; set; }

        public virtual Offer Offer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code from your models. Also, take a look at the generated migrations to see what's happening and if the types are properly mapped to the expected tables.

Comment: @Knelis Added code - the generated migrations have nothing uncommon, they are mapped to correct tables sadly.

Comment: @JCode Your code shows than an Offer can have ***zero*** or many OfferPlaces, does your query return an empty OfferPlaces list for all Offers?

Comment: @CraftedPod Yes, even thought in the database - I have at least 2 places per offer. Plus, as I said - OfferPlace.Offer loads fine - meaning there are Offers with non-empty OfferPlaces.

Comment: @JCode If you still need help, we can discuss this at [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223272/room-for-crafted-pod-and-jcode)